# How to find maximum and minimum number in a text file shell script

Tags: shell

I have the following file:

T$57  abc string  (50.00,110.00)
T$97  xyz string  (30.00,-1100.00)

I need to put (50.00,110.00) , (30.00,-1100.00) in new file and finally saving the maximum number for x-coordinate in variable and minimum number for y-coor. in another variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk` as illustrated below. The coordinates are saved into another file called `file2` and the variables containing the max and min are `maxX` and `minY` respectively.

```
$ cat file
T$57  abc string  (50.00,110.00)
T$97  xyz string  (30.00,-1100.00)

$ read maxX minY < <(awk -F"[ (,)]+" 'NR==1 { maxX=$4;minY=$5 } {if($4>maxX){maxX=$4} if($5<miny){miny=$5}print "("$4","$5")" > "file2"}END{print maxX" "miny}' file)

$ echo $maxX
50.00

$ echo $minY
-1100.00

$ cat file2
(50.00,110.00)
(30.00,-1100.00)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little shell script :

```
#!/bin/bash

maxx=0
miny=0
#For everithing between brackets in you file do
for i in `grep -oE '\(([^\(\)]*)\)' file` ; do

 echo $i >> newFile

 #Getting the differnts values
 j=`echo $i | tr -d '[\(][\)]'`
 x=`echo $j | cut -d, -f1`
 y=`echo $j | cut -d, -f2`

 #Putting the max in maxx
 if [ $maxx \< $x ] ; then
  maxx=$x
 fi

 #Putting the min in miny
 if [ $miny \> $y ] ; then
  miny=$y
 fi

done

echo $maxx
echo $miny
```